# passing arguments for summaries dplyr package in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I am writing a function with some arguments `summary_fn <- function(data,...,select_var,fun)`. The first argument is data, second is group_by, third is variable, the last one is multiple choices for `summarise`

Is there any way we can map in `summarise` function with eval(parse(text= exp))? Or anyway will help?

```
summary_fn <- function(data,...,select_var,fun){
  
  group <- ensyms(...)
  var <- ensym(select_var)
  
  name <- c()
  expr <- c()
  
  for( i in 1:length(fun)){
    exps  <- fun[[i]]
    exps  <- ensym(exps)
    name[[i]] <- paste0(quo_name(exps),"_", quo_name(var))
    expr[[i]] <- paste0(exps,"(",var,", na.rm = TRUE)")
  }
  
  print(name)
  print(expr)
  
  data %>% group_by(!!!group) %>% summarise(.......)
  
}

summary_fn(mtcars,cyl, am, select_var = mpg,fun = c("mean","max","min"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

summary_fn <- function(data, ..., select_var, fun) {   
    group <- enquos(...)
    var <- enquo(select_var)   
    funs <- map(setNames(fun, fun), ~.x)   
    data %>% 
        group_by(!!!group) %>% 
        summarise(across(!!var, funs), .groups = "drop")  
}

summary_fn(mtcars, cyl, am, select_var = mpg, fun = c("mean", "max"))
## A tibble: 6 x 4
#    cyl    am mpg_mean mpg_max
#  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4     0     22.9    24.4
#2     4     1     28.1    33.9
#3     6     0     19.1    21.4
#4     6     1     20.6    21  
#5     8     0     15.0    19.2
#6     8     1     15.4    15.8
```

If you provide `fun` as a named `list` you can skip the `funs <- map(...)` step.

PS. Replacing `enquo` with `ensym` and `enquos` with `ensyms` also works.

Comment: The across() is not working, I tried to update dplyr

Comment: Hi @Ben. What do you mean it's not working? I've got no errors on my side. `across` was introduced in `dplyr_1.0.0`; do you mean to say that you are running an older `dplyr` version and are unable to upgrade?

Comment: PS. You can achieve the same with the older scoped verb `summarise_at` but this is discouraged as all scoped verbs have been superseded (due to `across`).

Comment: How we set na,rm = TRUE when we call funs?

Comment: I got it, just add na.rm = TRUE

Comment: I have a question, how I add quantile in funs?

Comment: That becomes a bit more complicated, as `quantile` returns a vector. Depending on your expected output format, you'd probably have to start looking into a `map(funs, exec, ...)`-type solution (formerly `invoke_map`). If you edit your post to include your expected output, it'll be easier to provide a specific solution.

Comment: I got the quantile